# In a unix timestamp should there be numbers after a decimal point?

Tags: c#, unix-timestamp

When I generate my unix timestamp using the below code, I get two numbers after the decimal point, like this :  `1389200512.12`

Should those numbers be here? Do they mean anything? Are those fractions of milliseconds?

```
private double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    //create Timespan by subtracting the value provided from
    //the Unix Epoch
    TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));

    //return the total seconds (which is a UNIX timestamp)
    return Math.Round((double)span.TotalSeconds,2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are fractions of a second.

Comment: A unix timestamp is an integral value, the number of milliseconds since 1970.  Your method should not return double but *int* or *long*.

Comment: @HansPassant if you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter said they are fractions of a second because you call span.TotalSeconds. 1389200512.12 aren't milliseconds since the epoch but seconds since the epoch. If you want milliseconds you should call span.TotalMilliseconds